# Carrierwave uploaded images not displaying on rails 4 using S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

Using Carrierwave and Amazon S3 images are not showing in this code

```
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="innerPictureFrame">
    <% @gallery.gamepics.each do |gamepic| %>
      <div class="gamepic">
        <%= image_tag(gallery.gamepic.thumb.to_s, :size => '200x200') %>
        <div class="name"><%= gamepic.name %></div>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= link_to "edit", edit_gamepic_path(gamepic) %>
          <%= link_to "remove", gamepic, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
        </div>
     </div>
    <% end %>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and this controller

```
def create
  @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)
    if @gallery.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created gallery."
      redirect_to @gallery
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

Using the sample from railscast 253

Edit-  I checked the Postgres DB on heroku and that seems fine  so its either a display error or a model error

Models -

Gamepic

```
class Gamepic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  mount_uploader :gamepic, GamepicUploader

  private 
    def gamepic_params
      params.require(:gamepic).permit(:gameid, :gamename, :gamepic)
    end
end
```

Gallery

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gamepics

  private 
    def gallery_params
      params.require(:gallery).permit(:name, :gallery, :gamepic)
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you seeing your image in your S3 bucket? If so, it's a problem with your calling it from Rails, else you've got a problem with uploading to S3

Comment: Yea they show up on the bucket

Comment: Can you call `gamepic_url` for your `image_tag`?

Comment: tried that does nothing.

Comment: Just as a secondary options can you try `tag(:img , src: gallery.gamepic.thumb.to_s)`  know `image_tag` internally does the same but still